# Center Form on page with Flexbox and Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

Trying to center align the button.  I'll also be putting a form in that area so I need like a box or container that's dead middle of the page.  Right now for some reason even though I specified a max height and width of 100% the button is centered which is good, but still at the very top.

I probably need like an extra box also just to act as a container around the form stuff that sits inside the root Box I assume.

I'm not sure if I'm specifying the property names right like `alignItems` since this is styled objects and you can't have `align-items` as a prop for example.

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Box } from '@material-ui/core';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    },
    button: {
        background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
        border: 0,
        borderRadius: 3,
        boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
        color: 'white',
        height: 48,
        padding: '0 30px'
    }
});

function Login() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <Box className={classes.root}>
            <Button className={classes.button}>Login</Button>
        </Box>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

[image]

Comment: Try setting root's `height` to `100vh`.

Comment: yes that worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will be because your "root" class is on the Box component - which will need its parent to have a height specified - otherwise it will not be able to adjust its own height to be 100% - or in other word - the  element has a height of 100% - but 100% of what?

Try setting the html, body and any other parent elements to have a height.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden
}
.root {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .button {
        background: linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%);
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 3;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3);
        color: white;
        height: 48;
        padding: 0 30px;
    }
```

```html
<Box class="root">
    <Button class="button">Login</Button>
</Box>
```